# When migrating from Quartz.Net 1.x to 2.x will I have to change the way my scheduler is configured and started?

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

Here is how I configure and start my Quartz.Net scheduler in 1.x:

```
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = instanceName;
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = threadCount;
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = tablePrefix;
properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "false";
properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = connectionString;
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";
schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
svcScheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
svcScheduler.Start();
```

After migrating to 2.x will I have to change something here and what?

Most importantly is `quartz.dataSource.default.provider` for SQL Server still `SqlServer-20` or did something change there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has really changed in the configuration of Quartz.net 2.x.
You can find some useful information [here](http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-does-quartznet-configuration-work.html).

Yes, you still have to use `SqlServer-20` if you want to use MS Sql Server.

For a full list of db provider have a look [here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Impl/AdoJobStore/Common/dbproviders.properties).